# Search is not working with lowercase LIKE for russian characters

Tags: postgresql

What is the reason for this query give no results:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%после%');
```

When this works fine:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%После%');
```

Name is 'Последователь'. If i use name like 'Post', then search works fine.

Version: PostgreSQL 11.2 (Ubuntu 11.2-100) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0, 64-bit

Server and db encoding is UTF8. Client encoding is UNICODE.

[image]

Comment: And check `Query Editor`'s charset.

Comment: @Shawn.X client encoding is UNICODE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `lower` function works according to the database collation, so the result will vary depending on how your database is defined.

It will work well in this case:

```
test=# CREATE DATABASE rus TEMPLATE template0
       ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE "ru_RU.utf8" LC_CTYPE "ru_RU.utf8";
CREATE DATABASE
test=# \c rus
You are now connected to database "rus" as user "postgres".
rus=# SELECT LOWER('%после%') = LOWER('%После%');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

But it won't work with the `C` collation, because that does not know how to properly lower case cyrillic characters:

```
rus=# \c test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# DROP DATABASE rus;
DROP DATABASE
test=# CREATE DATABASE rus TEMPLATE template0
       ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE "C" LC_CTYPE "C";
CREATE DATABASE
test=# \c rus
You are now connected to database "rus" as user "postgres".
rus=# SELECT LOWER('%после%') = LOWER('%После%');
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

So if you want your query to work well, make sure that you are using a collation that knows how to convert the characters to upper and lower case.

Comment: Mast be ru_RU.UTF-8

Comment: @shilovk That depends on your C library and on the locales you have configured. `locale -a` shows the whole list on Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 1):

Functions `LOWER` and `UPPER` do not work correct if database has wrong locale.

Step-1. View locale of databases in Postgres:

```
\l
```

Step-2. View available locales in terminal:

```
locale -a
```

or by your language, for example `ru`:

```
locale -a | grep ru
```

Step-3. Use locale name from Step-2(for example `ru_RU.UTF-8`) in updating database `YOUR_DATABASE_NAME` in Postgres:

```
update pg_database set datcollate='ru_RU.UTF-8', datctype='ru_RU.UTF-8' where datname='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';
```

or you can create new database with locale:

```
CREATE DATABASE NEW_DATABASE_NAME TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING UTF8 LC_COLLATE "ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE "ru_RU.UTF-8";
```

PS My macOS has name `ru_RU.UTF-8`, Ubuntu has name `ru_RU.utf8`

Comment: Don't apply UPDATE operation on an existing database, as it may corrupt existing indexes and queries. See here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/275533/is-it-possible-to-change-collation-for-an-existing-database-with-postgresql

Answer (score -1):

Look Closer. LIKE statement is sometimes case sensitive. Depens on the program you use

The first statement is  :

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%после%');
```

while the second is :

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%После%');
```

What you seek is

> **П**  оследователь

note that in the first statement you wrote with **(п)** while the second one is **(П)**

Comment: what does LOWER(name) does?

Comment: lower casing string

Comment: Maybe you don't realize it, but `п` is a lower case `П` in Cyrillic.